How to Handle Errors with Messages in ResponseEntity in Spring?
How should error responses be handled properly? When I need to return a class, I use ResponseEntity<Class>. However, if I want to return an error as plain text (string), I would need to use ResponseEntity<String> with string as the return type. What is the best practice in this case? Should I instead map the error to a JSON format
and use ResponseEntity string?
For example I have:
When my return type is Mono<ResponseEntity<UserAccessData>>, I need to return UserAccessData in successful scenarios. However, when an error occurs, I want to return a ResponseEntity<String> with an error message. Should I convert all responses, including UserAccessData and error messages, to JSON and set the return type to Mono<ResponseEntity<String>>? Or is there a better approach to handle this?
  @PostMapping("/login")
public Mono<ResponseEntity<UserAccessData>> authorizeUser(@RequestBody @Valid LoginData loginData) {
    return userPort.login(loginData)
            .map(userAccessData -> ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(userAccessData))
            .onErrorResume(ex -> Mono.just(ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("User authorization failed: " + ex.getMessage())));
}


You should use @RestControllerAdvice. Something like this.

I analyze a few different approach and Thank you. I think that this is the best idea.
